# Provisioning gas in contract to pay during a method

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Is it possible to provision a contract with Wei that can be used to pay the gas for future method invocations?

After creating the contract with Wei, I would like to reduce the price to invoke a method.

Comment: It sounds like this question is similar to http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144/can-contracts-pay-the-gas-instead-of-the-message-sender